# How to: Gradle Build spring boot app with external config file

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

Maven way is very simple:

```
mvn clean install -Dspring.config.location=/path/config.properties
```

How can I do this with Gradle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify a task and add jvmArgs for running spring boot application in build.gradle file:

```
bootRun {
        jvmArgs = ["-Dspring.config.location=/prop.properties"]
}
```

or run in command line:

```
gradle clean build bootRun -Drun.jvmArgs="-Dloader.config.location=/path/to/prop/file"
```