# How to pass spring.config.location="somepath" while building SpringBoot application with command-line Gradle (6.4) build

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, gradlew

I have a SpringBoot application where I have application.properties file outside of project (it's not in usual place src/main/resources).
While building application with `gradle clean build`, it fails as code is not able to find properties files.
I have tried many command to pass vm args, gradle opts but its not working.

```
gradle clean build -Djvmargs="-Dspring.config.location=/users/home/dev/application.properties" //not working
```

It fails on test phase when it creates Spring application context and not able to substitute property placeholders. If I skip test as `gradle clean build -x test` it works.

Though I can run the app with `java -jar api.jar --spring.config.location=file:/users/home/dev/application.properties`

Please help how I can pass `spring.config.location=/users/home/dev/application.properties` in gradle build using command line so that build runs with all Junit tests

Answer (score 2):

System properties for running Gradle are not automatically passed on to the testing framework. I presume this is to isolate the tests as much as possible so differences in the environment will not lead to differences in the outcome, unless explicitly configured that way.

If you look at the Gradle API for the [Test task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.html), you can see that you can configure system properties through through the `systemProperty` method on the task (Groovy DSL):

```
test {
    systemProperty "spring.config.location", "/path/to/my/configuration/repository/application.properties"
}
```

If you also want to read a system property from the Gradle command line and then pass that the test, you have to read it from Gradle first, e.g. as a project property, and then pass that value to the test:

```
test {
    if (project.hasProperty('testconfig')) {
        systemProperty 'spring.config.location', project.getProperty('testconfig')
    }
}
```

Run it with `gradle -Ptestconfig="/path/to/my/configuration/repository/application.properties" build`

However, I would discourage using system properties on the build command line if you can avoid it. At the very least, it will annoy you greatly in the long run. If the configuration file can be in different locations on different machines (depending on where you have checkout out the repository and if it is not in the same relative path to your Spring Boot repository), you may want to specify it in a personal `gradle.properties` file instead.

Comment: Great solution, it worked. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Bjorn Vester.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would not get involved the actual properties to junit test. So I would create a test properties for the project under `src/test/resources/application-test.properties` and in junit test I would load the test properties.

**Example:**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyProperties.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")
public class MyTestExample{

  @Test
  public void myTest() throws Exception {
  ...
  }

}
```

Comment: I can not have properties files inside project. It's a separate repo that contains application properties files. Also having different properties files for test would duplicate it.

Comment: Can you try the following command to your project 
`gradle clean build -Dspring.config.location=/users/home/dev/application.properties`

Comment: maybe this post will help you to pass application.property externally https://stackoverflow.com/a/52099774/13167832

Comment: I had tried this already. It does not work. I need args to 'build' not to 'bootRun'.

Comment: If nothing works, I guess, I have to create different config files for Junit test as suggested by @nikob-bob

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a misunderstanding.

## spring.config.location is used at runtime

As you validated:

`java -jar api.jar --spring.config.location=file:/users/home/dev/application.properties`

**spring.config.location** is used or required at runtime, **not at build time.**

When your spring boot app is building, an **application.properties** is required. An approach could be use an **src/main/resources/application.properties** with template values, but at runtime you will ignore it `spring.config.location=file...`

## For unit tests

In this case as @nikos-bob said, you must use another properties, commonly inside of your `src/test/resources`

## Environment variables instead external properties

We don't want to have hardcoded values in our main git repository **src/main/resources/application.properties** so the first idea is use an external properties. But this file must be stored in another git repository (equal to main repository ) or manually created.

Spring and other frameworks give us an alternative: **Use environment variables**.

So instead of manually external creation of **application.properties** or store it in our git repository, your spring boot app always must have an **application.properties** but with environment variables:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@${DATABASE_HOST}:${DATABASE_PORT}:${DATABASE_SID}
spring.datasource.username=${DATABASE_USER}
spring.datasource.password=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
spring.mail.host = ${MAIL_HOST}
spring.mail.username =${MAIL_USERNAME}
spring.mail.password =${MAIL_PASSWORD}
```

Advantages:

- No manually creation of application.properties allowing us a more easy devops automations
- No **spring.config.location=file..** is required

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. On application.properties not being used on build time, If I put application.properties file to src/main/resources, gradle clean build works. But if do not have it at resources folder then gradle clean build fails. It means at build time it needs application.properties files. This actually the way we have written the test case. As I said at test phase it starts the app.  But the question is how to specify external config file so that gradle clean build works.
May be we can not specify spring.config.location=file at build time, that what I am figuring out.

Comment: what about a properties with dummy values like `password = changeme` just for build. For your test issue, if you code a minimal repository in github maybe I can try to reproduce. Are you in windows?

Comment: As mentioned by you and @nikos-bob, if I create a different prop file for test, and use it in test, then build works fine. I have tested it. So it seems I can go with this approach. But it would have been perfect if I could just specify the path to config file for Gradle build in command line or say in build.gradle file.
And my code is in company hosted git repo.